# Can't return relationship element in json Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, api, eloquent

Im using Laravel with Resources to create REST Api. I would like to get a json with informations about relationship element like in example

```
{
"id": 30,
"calf": 23,
"chest": 27
"user_id": {
    "id": 30,
    "email": "test@example.com"
}}
```

But when I created code like in docs I got an error "Call to a member function first() on int". Could someone tell me what im doing wrong? I did exactly this same things like in docs, I tried also using whenLoaded but this same error. This is my code:

```
 class CircuitMeasurementResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
//        return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'calf' => $this->calf,
            'chest' => $this->chest,
            'user_id' => UserResource::collection($this->user_id)
        ];
    }
}
```

My method show in Controller:

```
public function show(CircuitMeasurement $circuitMeasurement): CircuitMeasurementResource {
        return new CircuitMeasurementResource($circuitMeasurement);
    }
```

My models:

```
    class CircuitMeasurement extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'calf', 'thigh', 'hips', 'waist', 'chest', 'neck', 'biceps'
    ];
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function weightMeasurement(){
        return $this->hasMany(WeightMeasurement::class);
    }
    public function circuitMeasurement(){
        return $this->hasMany(CircuitMeasurement::class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are wrong in your code:

1. In your `CircuitMeasurement`, change to:

```
// since it gets just one
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

2. You use `ResourceName::collection()` for multiple items, and `new ResourceName()` for single item. Change your Resource to:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
//        return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'calf' => $this->calf,
            'chest' => $this->chest,
            'user_id' => new UserResource($this->user)
           //I think you should name user instead of user_id
        ];
    }
```